# capture keyup event inside dynamically loaded iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, wysihtml5

I have a text editor which uses [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/). I think the text editor is loaded in an iframe. I need to capture the key up event inside the text editor. And how do i prevent scrolling inside this text editor.

The code below loads the text editor

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" maxlength="10000" class="span12 inbox-editor wysihtml5 m-wrap" rows="12">sample text</textarea>
```

any suggestion appreciated

Comment: What text editor you are using

Comment: wysihtml5 ,Open source rich text editor based on HTML5

Comment: `window.frames[0].document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){/*handle event*/ })`, where `frames[0]` is a reference to the first iframe within document, which may not be the case in your situation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using wysihtml5 by xing you can do it this way:

```
 $('.textarea').wysihtml5({
    events: {
      load: function() {
        $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').on("keydown",function(event) {
          //your key event
        }); 
      }
    }
  });
```

I don't get the point what the problem is with scrolling.

Comment: it works great this way, I was having a conflict with my own built picture gallary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with [@Waxolunish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534858/waxolunist), here is a sample implementation where I try to capture the "tab" keypress event:

```
$('#wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
  $(elem).wysihtml5({
    "font-styles": true,
    "emphasis": true,
    "lists": true, 
    "html": true, 
    "link": true,
    "image": true,
    "color": false,
    "events": {
      "focus": function() {
        $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').on("keydown",function(event) {          
          event.preventDefault();              
          var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

          if (keyCode == 9){
             // do something & remember to add all the closing tags..
```

Good luck!